# Verificar resultado JSON no Login com Angular 2x

Tags: angular, angular-6

Meu service para entrar tem:

```
entrar(data: any): Observable<any> {
  console.log(data.email, data.senha);
  return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/` + '?email=' + `${data.email}` + '&senha=' + `${data.senha}`);  
}
```

E meu componente de "login" o botão de entrar tem:

```
login() {
    this.jogadorService.entrar(this.user)
        .subscribe(() => {
            this.jogadorService.entrar(this.user);          
            alert('Login feito');
            //this.router.navigate(['/login'])
        });
  }
```

Mas ele aceita qualquer dado. Queria verificar se usuário e senha existem mesmo e são iguais. E se retornar o JSON vazio `{}` então mostrar mensagem.

Como posso fazer?

Aproveitando o expaço, se o resultado for correto armazenar no LocalStorage o resultado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A segunda chamada ao `jogadorService` não esta fazendo nada, já que não é dado um `subscribe` nela. Então pode retira-lo.

A função `subscribe` é a que executa de fato a chamada ou executa a função, que no seu caso é uma requisição HTTP. O resultado da requisição é passada no primeiro callback, chamado também de `next()`. O `next` recebe um valor que pode ser nomeado de sua maneira, no seu caso essa variavel foi descatada devido ao uso do `()`.

Sabendo disso a sua chamada de requisição, com a comparação de valores recebidos do back-end deve ser a seguinte:

```
login() {
    this.jogadorService.entrar(this.user)
        .subscribe(resultado => {
            // ... logica de comparacao   
            resultado.login === "admin" // <~ exemplo

            alert('Login feito');
            this.router.navigate(['/login'])
        });
}
```